# select query by id in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i have two tables look like that.

**test_suite**

```
id    project_id    name
 10       76         tt
 9        76         nn
 8        7          ee
```

**test_suite_run**

```
id    test_suite_id  name
29          10       sss
28          10       ttt
27          9        jjj
26          7        gdgg
25          8        tttt
24          1        oooo
```

here, test_suite_id is the reference id with test_suite table. now i want a **where** query with **project_id(say project_id=76)** where the output will look like

```
id   project_id    test_suite_id  name
29      76               10       sss
28      76               10       ttt
27      76               9        jjj
```

Comment: i'm new and so week on query. i can't take decision how to execute this.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You want a simple `JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
     tsr.id
    ,ts.project_id
    ,tsr.test_suite_id
    ,tsr.[name]
FROM test_suite_run tsr
JOIN test_suite ts  
    ON tsr.test_suite_id = ts.id
WHERE ts.project_id = 76
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Active records

```
  $this->db->where('test_suite.project_id', $project_id);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('test_suite');
    $this->db->join('test_suite_run' ,'test_suite.project_id=test_suite_run. project_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

this query will help you ..

```
 $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('test_suite');
  $this->db->join('test_suite_run', 'test_suite_run.project_id = test_suite.test_suite_id');
  $this->db->where('test_suite.project_id =', $project_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a join of both tables.

```
$table = $this->db->select("r.*,t.project_id")
->join("test_suite t","t.id = r.test_suite_id")
->get('test_suite_run r')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$CI->db->select('tsr.id,ts.project_id,tsr.test_suite_id,tsr.name');
$CI->db->from('test_suite_run tsr');
$CI->db->join('test_suite ts', 'ts.id = tsr.test_suite_id', 'left');
$query = $CI->db->get();
```

Comment: Please explain your solution in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('test_suite');
$this->db->join('test_suite_run', 'test_suite_run.test_suite_id   = test_suite.id');
$this->db->where('test_suite.project_id','76');
$query = $this->db->get();`

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter you can use query builder like this....

```
$this->db->select('test_suite_run.id,test_suite.project_id,test_suite_run.test_suite_id,test_suite_run.name');
$this->db->from('test_suite');
$this->db->join('test_suite_run', 'test_suite_run.test_suite_id   = test_suite.id');
$this->db->where('test_suite.project_id','76');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Take more reference from here...https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html